# How do I resolve npm command errors

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the following error coming up when I type npm commands in command prompts (windows 10)

> ```
> C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs>npm
> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

Comment: Nodejs inside the XAMPP directory? But XAMPP is a PHP development environment, why would Nodejs be in there?

Comment: Also you have an extra backslash \ in your path after `nodejs`, I guess it's screwing things up

Comment: @JeremyThille No,its not working

Comment: What happens when you run an actual `npm` command instead of just `npm` by itself. For example; What happens if you run `npm -v` to discover the version of npm? Or, what happens if you run `npm show eslint versions` to discover what versions of eslint are available in the registry.

Comment: Am getting the same error whenever i run npm command in command prompt